# Variable is not accessing inside query in php function

Tags: javascript, php, oop

I passed a variable using ajax to function inside my php file "Cart_code.php". Why variable is not accessing inside the function?

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/Cart_code.php",
    data: {ID:id},
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }

});
     });

});
</script>
```

Cart_code.php

```
function cart_head_info_print()
{
    if(isset($_POST['ID']))
    { 
        //Here the id is accessing. To make it accessible inside query, i made it global 
        echo $GLOBALS['pro_id'] = $_POST['ID'];
    }

    parent::db();
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $pro_id =  $GLOBALS['pro_id'];

    $query = "SELECT product_name , product_description from cart WHERE u_email = '$email' and product_id = '$pro_id'";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "variable isn't accessing inside function" ? what variable ?

Comment: U r not calling function u r calling file. U need to call your function `cart_head_info_print();`

Comment: @niceman
i need to pass $_POST['ID'] inside query.

Comment: @devpro
 i need to pass $_POST['ID'] inside query. How can i do that ?

Comment: By calling this function inside your Php file `cart_head_info_print();`

Comment: @devpro
How ?
i don't understand

Comment: Just write this line outside the function `cart_head_info_print();`

Comment: devpro means when you put a url, that url should point to a file which has some statements to execute on the top level, defining the function without calling it won't do anything

Comment: @devpro
By calling outside, it's giving error because function is declared inside the class

Comment: Anyway besides devpro right advice, bassxzero's answer is what you want

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide is the class a Controller ? are you using any php framework ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function cart_head_info_print(){
      //this is for debugging. If this is empty/null/etc then you have a problem

      var_dump($_POST['ID']);          


     //$_POST is a super global so you don't need to do anything special

                parent::db();
                $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                $pro_id =  $POST['ID'];

                $query = "SELECT product_name , product_description from cart WHERE u_email = '$email' and product_id = '$pro_id'";
    }
// if you truly are missing the function call then you need this too, but I don't think you're missing this
cart_head_info_print();
```

**UPDATE 1**

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

I'm pretty positive you are using `parent::` incorrectly. I would remove it.

Comment: Also I'm not really sure what ` parent::db();` is for. `parent::` is only for methods not functions. Is this code for a method or function?

Comment: this is parent function. it contain database name and password. But my issue is still .             Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\includes\Cart_code.php on line 517
NULL 
Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\includes\Cart_code.php on line 524

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide are you using codeignitor ? symphony ? yii ? laravel ? any framework ?

Comment: i am using object oriented php not using any framework.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide change `data: {ID:id},` to `data: {ID:5},` for example and see if it works

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide add `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of Cart_code.php

Comment: this line output is                   array(0) { }          and error still.

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading ?

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide if your other scripts are populating $_POST and you are truly accessing Cart_code.php from a ajax script then there shouldn't be a problem.